# Looping through input file not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a jquery plugin which is rendered inside form  in browser like

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <form...>  
   <input type="file" id="ajax-upload-id-1496226711376" name="upload[]" accept="*" multiple="" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 0;">
  ... 
  </form>
    ...
     <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Note that submit button is not the part of the plugin

I have tried the following

```
          $("#submit").click(function() {

           var files = $("input:file")[0].files;

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
              alert(files[i].name);
            }

           });
```

It is not working!!!

Please help...

Comment: Works just fine for me, take a look https://jsfiddle.net/70pns7kk/

Comment: mine too works ok

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Any alerts in your console? Maybe add `console.log(files)` after you define the `files` variable to ensure that it is populated with the data you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can only guess since I don't know which plugin you are using. But you said that the form content is rendered/replaced by the plugin. So maybe jQuery can't access the input since it was not recognized by jQuery when loading. So maybe something like this can help you out? If not then please tell us what plugin you are using and maybe provide some more code.

```
$("#submit").click(function() {

    var files = $(document).find('input[type="file"]')[0].files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        alert(files[i].name);
    }
});
```

Please note that this is just a guess based on the working example in the comments...

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work for you.

**JavaScript**

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var files = $("input:file")[0].files;
  console.log("Files uploaded:", files);
  $.each(files, function(key, val) {
    console.log(val.name);
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/j5c5qvg4/

Or: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/j5c5qvg4/3/